# ONOS does not find the generated .OAR

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, onos

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/jatj/httpDetector) project for some lab tests. The fact is that when I activate the application on my ONOS controller the application crashes with the following error.

[image-error-karaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV0G9.png)

I have been investigating and searching in various forums but none of them clarify the solution to the error.

Any help or clarification is appreciated.

All the best.

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the file. I have already updated the question with the image of the logs.

Comment: Well done my friend, but try to upload as the plain text format. Images can't be copied, and it is the policy here :)